# Does ascending keyword exist purely for clarity when used with orderby?

Tags: c#, linq, sql-order-by, keyword

If i do a query, ordering elements as below, i get ascending order.

```
var i = from a in new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }
        orderby a
        select a;
```

If i add the `ascending` keyword i get the same results.

```
var i = from a in new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }
        orderby a ascending
        select a;
```

I recognise that adding the `ascending` keyword in the second example could increase readability as it removes the need to know the default order of `orderby`.

**Is there any other reason for the `ascending` keyword to exist?**

I'm also, interested in knowing why this (breaking change?) was implimented just for use in one particular case.

Edit: See comments below, @Joey points out, it's not a breaking change as it's a contextual keyword.

Comment: What if it wasn't there, and people ask "how do I specify ascending order?" Like you said, it's for readability. If there's a `descending` clause I don't think there's anything wrong with having a corresponding `ascending` clause.

Comment: Fair enough. See my edit; I know MS don't introduce breaking changes lightly (am i right that it is a breaking change?) and to me it doesn't seem to be a much-needed keyword.

Comment: Why should it be a breaking change? LINQ query expressions are all made up of contextual keywords. They don't break anything that was legal before (afaik).

Comment: @Joey, if someone had a class or variable etc. named `ascending` then i think it would break.

Comment: No, it doesn't. That's the whole point of the contextual keywords.

Comment: @Joey. Ahhh, makes much more sense now, i thought any keyword was off limits, contextual or otherwise.

Comment: Not all keywords in C# are also *reserved* words :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it is redundant. There is no circumstance when it does anything different since the order is implicitly ascending.

I guess it provides completeness, but it does indeed seem a shame to introduce a keyword into the language that is so... impotent.

On the other side, though:

- it mimics SQL, which is broadly related in terms of semantics
- it avoids the "how do I?" questions
- it does no harm, and nobody is forcing you to use it
- it (arguably) makes things clearer if you have `a descending, b ascending, c descending, d ascending` etc

---

Example (see comments) that `order by a, order by b` is actually very different to `order by a, b`:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var data = new[] { new { X = 1, Y = 1 }, new { X = 1, Y = 2 },
                       new { X = 2, Y = 1 }, new { X = 2, Y = 2 } };

    foreach (var pair in from p in data orderby p.X, p.Y select p)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0},{1}", pair.X, pair.Y);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
    foreach (var pair in from p in data orderby p.X orderby p.Y select p)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0},{1}", pair.X, pair.Y);
    }
}
```

prints:

```
1,1
1,2
2,1
2,2

1,1
2,1
1,2
2,2
```

note the middle two are reversed. This is because of the difference between:

```
data.OrderBy(p => p.X).ThenBy(p => p.Y)
```

in the first loop, and

```
data.OrderBy(p => p.X).OrderBy(p => p.Y)
```

in the second.

Because LINQ attempts to guarantee a stable sort (i.e. when there are matches, the data is retained in the original order), an `OrderBy().OrderBy()` does the *first* sort (on X), and then **resorts** the data, only looking at the original (sorted by X) order when the Ys match. Or in other words: it flips them left-to-right.

Comment: +1 Didn't realise you could do `orderby a descending, b descending` i've always done `orderby a descending\n orderby b descending`

Comment: @George - interestingly, that actually does something different; the `orderby a, orderby b` technically treats `b` as the **primary** sort, and `a` as the secondary. So this *reverses* the sort precedence, for reasons related to stable sort, etc. Will add an example.

Comment: it always annoyed (to strong a word) me that i had to have the most significant sort last doing it the only way i knew. Great that there's a more consise, more self-explanitory (to me) ordering.

Comment: +1 for the "it avoids the "how do I?" questions" - I wonder how many language features arise from this desire?